# Flutter, How to provide TimeStamp() 's arguments as firebase's time stamp data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Cloud firestore has TimeStamp data, I am fetching it and displaying it in a datatable widget. To covert it to desired date format, I used `DateFormat('yMd').Format()`. But `format()` only accepts datetime and not timestamp. So, to convert firebase timestamp data to date time I used `TimeStamp().toDate()`. But `TimeStamp()` accepts seconds and nanoseconds. I tried providing firebase timestamp data in this format `data['paidDate']` I get error, How do I fix this.

```
return Center(
                            child: Container(
                          child: DataTable(
                              columns: const [
                                DataColumn(label: Text('Amount')),
                                DataColumn(label: Text('Paid Date'))
                              ],
                              rows: snapshot.data!.docs.map((data) {
                                // DateTime datee = data['paidDate'];
                                return DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(Text(data['amount'])),
                                  DataCell(Text(DateFormat('yMd')
                                      .format(Timestamp(data['paidDate']).toDate())))
                                ]);
                              }).toList()),
                        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a converter function.
Here is a example

```
///timestamp to date
  static DateTime _dateTimeFromTimeStamp(Timestamp timestamp) => DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var docs = Firebase.instance.doc(<id>).get();
Map<String, dynamic> data = docs.data!() as Map<String, dynamic>;
DateTime time = (data['timestamp'] as TimeStamp ).toDate();
```

Now time is of type DateTime. Pass it to `.format()`